# Properties of spectral decomposition

Tags: multivariate-analysis, matrix, computational-statistics, linear-algebra

**Spectral Decomposition**

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $k\times k$ positive definite matrix with the spectral decomposition $\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}^{\prime}$.
Let the normalized eigenvectors be the columns of another matrix $\mathbf{P}=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf{e}_{1}, & \mathbf{e}_{2}, & \ldots, & \mathbf{e}_{k}\end{bmatrix}$.
Then

$
\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}^{\prime}=\mathbf{P}\Lambda\mathbf{P}^{\prime}
$

where $\mathbf{P}\mathbf{P}^{\prime}=\mathbf{P}^{\prime}\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{I}$
and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix

$
\Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_{1} & 0 & \ldots & 0\\
0 & \lambda_{2} & \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & \ldots & \lambda_{k}
\end{bmatrix}\textrm{ with }\lambda_{i}>0.
$

**R Code**

```
A <- matrix(data=c(1, 0, 1, 3), nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
eigen(A)
eigen(A)$vectors %*% diag(eigen(A)$values) %*% t(eigen(A)$vectors)
```

**Output**

```
$values
[1] 3 1

$vectors
     [,1]       [,2]
[1,]    0  0.8944272
[2,]    1 -0.4472136

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]  0.8 -0.4
[2,] -0.4  3.2
```

I don't know what I'm missing here. I'm not able to prove $\mathbf{A}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}\mathbf{e}_{i}^{\prime}=\mathbf{P}\Lambda\mathbf{P}^{\prime}
$ with $
\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\
1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$. I also got the same results with hand calculations. I'd highly appreciate if you guide me what I'm missing here. Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Comment: i am somewhat new hear but if I am learning correctly this problem sounds like it might fall into the homework problem category and hence be designated as such.  Also although you use the key word multivariate analysis and computational statistics and these result could be applied to some of problems in these fields it really looks like a question more appropriate for the mathematics site.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: Thanks for your notice and comment. This is not a homework problem.

Comment: **Hint**: What is the definition of *symmetric*?

Comment: Thanks @cardinal for your comment. As I understood from your comment only symmetric matrices would be positive definite. Am I right? If so please change your comment to answer so that I can accept it for future users. Thanks

Comment: I have spent some time at the mathematics site and in my judgement they owuld have more interest in this question and are likely to give long detailed answers if that is what you want.

Comment: MYaseen2008: Two things: Only *symmetric* matrices have an eigendecomposition of the type you describe and they need not be positive definite, either (i.e., *all* symmetric matrices have such a decomposition). Second, many authors implicitly assume symmetry as part of the definition of positive definiteness while others do not. I'm more than happy to give you a full detailed answer here since these matrices have many statistical applications, but @Michael is correct in asserting this is a marginally better fit on the math site.

Comment: For an NxN matrix to be positive definite it must have a non-zero determinant.  You have say a diagonal matrix with a zero on the diagonal. Then the determinant will be 0 but the matrix will be symmetric.  So this is a symmetric matrix that is not positive definite.  I think the correct theorem in matrix algebra is that every symmetric matrix is positive semi-definite.  That is I believe the point cardinal is making.

Comment: @MichaelChernick: A symmetric matrix need not be positive semidefinite either. Just think of a diagonal matrix with at least one negative entry on the diagonal.

Comment: Right but there is a theorem like this. Maybe it is that every positive semidefinite symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. Forgive me for not remembering this correctly. I took linear algebra in college in 1966 about 46 years ago.

Comment: If I have finally got the theorem right which can easily be checked from any linear algebra book the problem is that the matrix in your example is not symmetric.

Comment: I checked positive definite on Wikipedia.  Not all positive definite matrices are symmetric and a characterization related  positive definiteness is that it that a Hermitian Matrix is positive definite iff it has all eigenvalues positive.  It is Hermitian matrices that have the property of an eignevalue decomposition.  Hermitian matrices are matrices with complex valued entries that have the element aij= the conjugate transpose of aji.  So if all the entries are real Hermitian Matrices are symmetric. So my answer is correct. The problem is the matrix you are using is not Hermitian.

Comment: Since $$(P\Lambda P^\prime)^\prime = (P^\prime)^\prime \Lambda^\prime P^\prime = P\Lambda P^\prime,$$ **every** matrix of this form is symmetric.  Since $A$ is not symmetric, it cannot be written in this form.  However, *if we understand $A$ to represent the quadratic form* $$Q_A:(x_1,x_2)\to(x_1,x_2)A(x_1,x_2)^\prime=x_1^2+x_1x_2+3x_2^2,$$ then indeed there exist a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ and orthogonal matrix $P$ for which $Q_A = Q_{P\Lambda P^\prime}$. From this point of view the essence of the question concerns what $A$ is taken to *mean* rather than whether it is symmetric or not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the particular example in the question, the properties of a *symmetric* matrix have been confused with those of a *positive definite* one, which explains the discrepancies noted.

**A brief tour of symmetry and positive semidefiniteness**

Symmetric positive (semi)definite matrices play an important role in
statistical theory and applications, making it useful to briefly
explore some of their properties and from whence they arise. The proofs can be made reasonably short, making it feasible to do this exploration here.

**A word on notation**. Let $\newcommand{\reals}{\mathbb R}A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix
with real-valued entries. Often, this is denoted $A \in
M_n(\reals)$. In what follows, $\lambda$ will be an eigenvalue of $A$
and $v$ will be a corresponding unit eigenvector, i.e., $A v = \lambda
v$ and $\|v\|_2 = 1$. Even though $A$ is real-valued, $\lambda$ and $v$ both might be
complex-valued, which is an important point to keep in mind. The notation $v^T$ denotes the transpose of $v$ if it
is real-valued and $v^*$ denotes the *conjugate* transpose. The conjugate of $z \in \mathbb C$ is denoted $\bar z$.

**Spectral decomposition and symmetry**

For this part, we'll assume $A$ is symmetric, that is, $A = A^T$.

> **Theorem 1** The eigenvalues of $A$ are real.
>   *Proof*: We have $$ \lambda = \lambda v^* v = v^* A v = \sum_i a_{ii} v_i \bar v_i + \sum_{i < j} a_{ij} (v_i \bar v_j + \bar v_i v_j) \>,$$ where the last equality follows from the fact that $a_{ij} = a_{ji}$. Note that all of the terms in each sum on the right-hand
>   side are real. Hence, $\lambda$ is real.

The result above gives our first hint at what any potential eigendecomposition must look like. To get a further hint, consider the following.

> **Theorem 2** The eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are orthogonal.
>   
> *Proof*: Let $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$    with corresponding $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then $$ \lambda_1 v_1^* v_2 = v_1^* A^* v_2 = v_1^* A v_2 = \lambda_2 v_1^* v_2 \>,  $$ so, $(\lambda_1 - \lambda_2) v_1^* v_2 = 0$ and since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, we must have $v_1^* v_2 = 0$.

So now we know that *distinct* eigenvalues yield orthogonal eigenvectors. But, we still don't know that the eigenvectors themselves are (i.e., can be *chosen* to be) real-valued.

> **Theorem 3** The eigenvectors of each eigenvalue can be chosen to be real-valued.
>   
> *Proof*: Decompose $v = u + i w$ where $u$ and $w$ are real-valued vectors. Then, $$ \lambda u + i \lambda w = \lambda v = A v = Au + i A w \>, $$ and $\lambda$ and $A$ are both real-valued, hence $A u = \lambda u$ and $A w = \lambda w$. This shows that
>   if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, so is $u$ (and $w$, for that matter).

So, we've got some real eigenvalues and some real eigenvectors that are orthogonal whenever the eigenvalues are distinct. Now we handle the case where a particular eigenvalue has *multiple* linearly independent eigenvectors.

> **Theorem 4** The (real) eigenvectors of a common eigenvalue form a vector subspace of $\reals^n$.
>   
> *Proof*: If $A v_1 = \lambda v_1$ and $A v_2 = \lambda v_2$, then   for any $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we have  $$ A (\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) = \alpha A v_1 + \beta A v_2 = \lambda (\alpha v_1 + \beta v_2) \>, $$
>   and so the set of vectors $\mathcal V = \{v: A v = \lambda v\}$ is a linear subspace.

Since every finite-dimensional real-valued linear subspace of
$\reals^n$ has an orthogonal basis, this is enough to conclude that
any symmetric $A$ satisfies $A V = V \Lambda$ where $V$ is an
orthogonal matrix and $\Lambda$ is a real-valued diagonal matrix. Note
that if it happens that there are less than $n$ nonzero eigenvalues,
that we can "fill out" the columns of $V$ with an orthogonal basis
of the remaining subspace and place zeros along the diagonal of $\Lambda$ in the corresponding locations.

Hence, there is some orthogonal $V$ and some real-valued diagonal
$\Lambda$ such that
$$
A = V \Lambda V^T \>.
$$
We can also see that the converse is trivially true. If $A = V \Lambda
V^T$, then $A^T = (V \Lambda V^T)^T = V \Lambda V^T = A$ and so $A$ is
symmetric.

**But, what about positive semidefiniteness?**

So far, we've said nothing about positive definiteness; all of the properties we have derived deal purely with symmetry. Now, we'll try to briefly develop the properties of positive definite matrices and make some connections to symmetry.

A matrix $A$ (not necessarily symmetric!) is called *positive semidefinite* if for all $x \in \reals^n$, we
have $x^T A x \geq 0$. If $x \neq 0$ further implies that $x^T A x>
0$, then $A$ is called *positive definite*. This arises
frequently in statistics in the study of quadratic forms.

> **Theorem 5** Let $A \in M_n(\reals)$. Then, there exists a   *symmetric* matrix $B$ such that $x^T A x = x^T B x$ for all $x \in \reals^n$.
>   
> *Proof*: $ x^T A x = (x^T A x)^T = x^T A^T x$ so choose $B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$.

Notice that there is nothing in the statement of the theorem about $A$ being positive semidefinite; it's completely general. What this says, though, is that when considering quadratic forms, we can always
implicitly assume that $A$ is symmetric. This motivates the fact that
oftentimes authors will assert that $A$ is symmetric immediately in the *definition*
of positive semidefiniteness.

> **Theorem 6** A symmetric positive semidefinite matrix $A$ has   nonnegative eigenvalues.
>   
> *Proof*: If $v$ is a unit eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then $$ \lambda = \lambda v^T v = v^T A v \geq 0 \>. $$

As an exercise, you should prove that if $A$ is symmetric positive definite,
then all eigenvalues must be *strictly* positive.

**A counterexample**

While the above shows that we can conclude that a symmetric $A$ having real positive eigenvalues is positive definite, this does not hold if we drop the symmetry requirement. Let 
$$
A = \left(\begin{array}{rr}1 & -4 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) \>.
$$
Then $A$ has an eigenvalue of 1 (with algebraic multiplicity of 2), but by taking $x$ to be a vector of ones we see
that $A$ is not positive semidefinite. The motivation for this example can be found in [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/134974/if-a-and-b-are-positive-semidefinite-matrices-then-is-ab2/135039#135039).