# Understanding the spectral decomposition of a Markov matrix?

Tags: pca, markov-process, matrix-decomposition

Why we do spectral decomposition of a Markov matrix, when a Markov matrix is not always symmetric?

Answer (score 5):

This is all from here: [http://cims.nyu.edu/~holmes/teaching/asa15/Lecture2.pdf](http://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eholmes/teaching/asa15/Lecture2.pdf) TLDR: you're still using the spectral decomposition theorem; you just have to find the right symmetric matrix.

### Detailed Balance

Let $P$ be your (say 2x2) transition matrix. It isn't symmetric. Let $\pi$ be the (1x2) stationary distribution vector. If the detailed balance equations hold, your Markov chain is reversible and this means that
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\pi_1 & 0 \\
0 & \pi_2  \end{array} \right) P = P' \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\pi_1 & 0 \\
0 & \pi_2  \end{array} \right).
$$

If we define
$$
\Lambda = \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{\pi_1} & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{\pi_2}  \end{array} \right),
$$
then you can re-write the above equation as
$$
\Lambda^2P = P'\Lambda^2.
$$

### Using the Spectral Decomposition Theorem

The link above claims $V = \Lambda P \Lambda^{-1}$ is symmetric. This can be verified using the previous formula, left multiplying both sides by by $\Lambda$ and right multiplying both sides by $\Lambda^{-1}$.

By the spectral decomposition theorem, $V$ is orthogonally diagonalizable. The link calls its eigenvectors $w_j$, and its eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ (for $j=1,2$ in this case). So $Vw_j = \lambda_j w_j$ and $w_j' V = w_j' \lambda_j$. Plugging in the definition of $V$, we get
$$
\Lambda P \Lambda^{-1} w_j = \lambda_j w_j
$$
and
$$
w_j' \Lambda P \Lambda^{-1} = w_j' \lambda_j.
$$
Premultiplying the former by $\Lambda^{-1}$ and the latter by $\Lambda$ we can verify the claim that $P$ has left eigenvectors $\psi_j = \Lambda w_j$ and right eigenvectors $\phi_j = \Lambda^{-1} w_j$. These could be written in terms of matrices as

$$
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\psi_1'  \\
\psi_2'  \end{array} \right)
P 
= 
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0  \\
0 & \lambda_2  \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\psi_1'  \\
\psi_2'  \end{array} \right)
$$

$$
P
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}\phi_1 &  \phi_2\end{array} 
\right)
= 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}\phi_1 &  \phi_2\end{array} 
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0  \\
0 & \lambda_2  \end{array} \right).
$$
Using the fact that $w_i'w_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$ and $1$ otherwise we can show that
\begin{align*}
P &= 
P 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}\phi_1 &  \phi_2\end{array} 
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\psi_1'  \\
\psi_2'  \end{array} \right) \\
&= 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}\phi_1 &  \phi_2\end{array} 
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0  \\
0 & \lambda_2  \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\psi_1'  \\
\psi_2'  \end{array} \right) \\
&= 
\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}\phi_1 &  \phi_2\end{array} 
\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
\lambda_1 & 0  \\
0 & \lambda_2  \end{array} \right)
\left( \begin{array}{c}
\phi_1' \Lambda^2  \\
\phi_2' \Lambda^2 \end{array} \right) \\
&= \sum_{k} \lambda_k \phi_k \phi_k' \Lambda^2.
\end{align*}

Comment: Did you mean to write $\psi_j = \Lambda^{-1}w_j$ instead?

Comment: Another question: doesn't this proof rely on the assumption that the detailed balance holds? If so, is it true that the balance always holds?

Comment: @MutasimMim no I didn't, but your question did help me find some other typos (now fixed), so thank you. And yes, this proof assumes detailed balance, which does not always hold.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is finding the stationary distribution of the states. As the other answer mentioned, symmetric is not the key. "diagonalizable" is more important. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83134/does-non-symmetric-positive-definite-matrix-have-positive-eigenvalues)

One related posts. [Properties of spectral decomposition](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28368/properties-of-spectral-decomposition) I think you will be clear if you read the accepted answer in this post.

> In the particular example in the question, the properties of a symmetric matrix have been confused with those of a positive definite one, which explains the discrepancies noted.

In addition, I personally feel this paper is explaining eigenvalue and eigenvector and iterative methods in a intuitive way. Feel free to check

https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake-papers/painless-conjugate-gradient.pdf